# Error: Invalid integer: NaN is not a valid exponent

Tags: react-native, web3js

I'm using `rn-nodeify` with my `React Native` app. It's a web3 based mobile app. When I run the code, it's working fine on iOS. But when I work with Android. Below error is getting on the `metro server`

> Error: Invalid integer: NaN is not a valid exponent.
> ERROR  Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication). A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect.
> This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.

This is my `shim.js` file!

```
if (typeof __dirname === "undefined") {
  global.__dirname = "/";
}
if (typeof __filename === "undefined") {
  global.__filename = "";
}
if (typeof process === "undefined") {
  global.process = require("process");
} else {
  const bProcess = require("process");
  for (var p in bProcess) {
    if (!(p in process)) {
      process[p] = bProcess[p];
    }
  }
}

process.browser = false;
if (typeof Buffer === "undefined") {
  global.Buffer = require("buffer").Buffer;
}

if (typeof BigInt === "undefined") {
  global.BigInt = require("big-integer");
}

// global.location = global.location || { port: 80 }
if (typeof location === "undefined") {
  global.location = { port: 80, protocol: "https:" };
}

const isDev = typeof __DEV__ === "boolean" && __DEV__;
process.env.NODE_ENV = isDev ? "development" : "production";
if (typeof localStorage !== "undefined") {
  localStorage.debug = isDev ? "*" : "";
}

Object.defineProperty(global, "_bitcore", {
  get() {
    return undefined;
  },
  set() {},
});

// If using the crypto shim, uncomment the following line to ensure
// crypto is loaded first, so it can populate global.crypto
require("crypto");
```

In side `package.json`, I have this script:

```
"postinstall": "patch-package & rn-nodeify --install fs,dgram,process,path,console,stream,events,crypto,zlib,micro-ftch,big-integer --hack",
```

I think it's something with `BigInt`. As you see, I'm using `big-integer`.
How can I fix this error?